# Change URL with .htaccess (redirect from old url to new url)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I used to use explode function for SEO url like :

```
site.com/?/category/id/topicname/ (or site.com/index.php?/category/id/topicname/)
```

However, I start to use `.htaccess`. But I have problem now. Old referrers can not reach the article. How can I change the url like :

from: `site.com/?/category/id/topicname/`

to:`site.com/category/id/topicname/`

and

from: `site.com/index.php?/category/id/topicname/`

to: `site.com/category/id/topicname/`

edit:
my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/$   index.php?modul=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$   index.php?modul=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9]+)\/?$   index.php?modul=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)\/?$   index.php?modul=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Old referrers" ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I think he means like permalinks on websites or facebook pages, he wants old links to redirect to the new URL format

Comment: Users posted my website link to other website, facebook, twitter etc. I change the url with .htaccess now. So, users try to read my article but link is different. How can I change url with .htaccess ? I just want to delete ?/ or index.php?/ part of site.com/?/category/id/name/.
@ShivanRaptor

Comment: Have a look at mod_rewrite

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't find the right pattern. I just want to remove index.php?/ or ?/ part. @aross

Comment: You should show your current `.htaccess` contents.

Comment: I add. I try to this but it is not work "RewriteRule ^?/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L]" @ShivanRaptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following directive to your `.htaccess`, the first condition assert no previous redirection was made (otherwise, it will be an endless loop)

```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/(.+)$
   RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /%1? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: it is not work. Sorry. I just want to redirect from
site.com/index.php?/category/id/topic/ to site.com/category/id/topic/

Comment: yes, that's what the above rules are supposed to do, do you get 500 error or what?

Comment: Thank you very much, i made a mistake. It is work now. Thank you.